# parse error, expecting 'T_FUNCTION' & class error function in php

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop, pdo

I'm getting the error like this

> parse error, expecting 'T_FUNCTION' on line 4

But this codes works fine when i'm not using classes. Before i didn't use classes in php code. I just write php codes without classes. Now, i want to use classes in my php code so, i've implemented some codes. But it throws me an above error. Where i made mistake here? (i thought i've made mistakes in class function).

**config.php**

```
<?php
class Configuration
{
    private $user = "root";
    private $password = "password";
    public $conn;

    public static function connect()
    {
        if(self::$instance = null)
        {
            try
            {
                $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_table', $user, $password);
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                'Database Connection Error' .$e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return
    }
}
?>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php
class StoreDatas
{
    include_once('config.php');
    if($_POST["register"] == "alldetails")
    {
        private $r_uname = trim($_POST["uname"]);
        private $r_email = trim($_POST["email"]);
        //some codes
            //some codes
            //some codes

        // name validation
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/", $r_uname))
        {
            echo '<b>Name</b> - Name must be from letters and spaces only';
            die();
        }
        // email validation
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]\w+(\.\w+)*\@\w+(\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/", $r_email) )
        {
            echo '<b>Email</b> - Email must comply with this mask: chars(.chars)@chars(.chars).chars(2-4)';
            die();
        }
        //some codes
            //some codes
            //some codes

        function InsertDatas
        {
            try
            {
                $stmt = Connection::connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO user_registration ( Name, EmailID, MobileNumber, Password, ReEnterPassword, UserProfileCreatedOn ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW() )");
                $conn->errorInfo();
                $stmt->bindParam('1', $r_uname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam('2', $r_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam('3', $r_mobile, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam('4', $r_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam('5', $r_reenterpassword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute();
                echo 'Registered Succesfully. You can login now';
                echo '<script type="text/JavaScript">$("#registrationform")[0].reset();</script>';
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo 'Failed to insert. Contact your admin' . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

This syntax is invalid

```
<?php
class StoreDatas
{
    include_once('config.php');
    if($_POST["register"] == "alldetails")
    {
```

You cannot use arbitrary code in class definition. Everything should be inside properties or functions.

So this code should be inside some method, probably constructor

It also has no point to do this. Your methods and properties cannot be inside conditions, and they don't have to be.

```
class X {
    if(true) {
        public function Y();
    }
}
```

is invalid syntax, and you also don't need it. The method will not be executed if you don't explicitly call it.

Also:

Initializing properties to data from the request should be done in constructor (or in user defined setter), not in the class definition.

Invalid:

```
class X {
    private $_y = $_POST['y'];
}
```

It should be

```
class X {
    private $_y;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->_y = $_POST['y'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

only properties or methods can be declared as class member.

To include files, you can either add all your `include` and `if` inside a __construct() method, or simply out of the class. To keep most of your code, you can do something like this:

```
include_once('config.php');

class StoreDatas
{
  public $r_uname;
  public $r_email;
  public function InsertDatas()
  {
     // ...
  }
}

 // The code out of the class

 $store_data = new StoreDatas();
 if($_POST["register"] == "alldetails")
 {
   $store_data->r_uname = trim($_POST["uname"]);
   $store_data->r_email = trim($_POST["email"]);
   //some codes

   // name validation
   if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/", $r_uname))
   {
     echo '<b>Name</b> - Name must be from letters and spaces only';
     die();
   }
   // email validation
   if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]\w+(\.\w+)*\@\w+(\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/", $r_email) )
    {
      echo '<b>Email</b> - Email must comply with this mask: chars(.chars)@chars(.chars).chars(2-4)';
      die();
    }
    //some code
    //some code
    //some code
}
```

Comment: -1: you made OP's code **worse**.